# OutOfMemoryError after executing a ThreadPoolExecutor many times

Tags: java, android, future, threadpoolexecutor, callable

I use a thread pool executor using Future and Callable instead of AyscTask, taking the advantage of the timeout feature to wait for a response that can take a while calling my own method that works ok called "isIdOk". This is the way I do the pool call:

```
public static boolean isOk(final Context context, final String id) {

    boolean result = false;

    final BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1);
    final ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
    Future<Boolean> future;

    future = threadPoolExecutor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() {
            return isIdOk(id);
        }
    });
    try {result = future.get(5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);}
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    future.cancel(true);
    return result;
}
```

I call this method (**isOk**) about 12 times per minute and works perfect, but after a while, the method throws me:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
```

in this line:

```
future = threadPoolExecutor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
```

Whatching arround Android Studio memory "**Profiler**", I observe that the "*native*" and "*others*" memory increase each time this method is called. I have try adding **future.cancel(true)** without success. It looks like the pool remains in memory even if it finishes.

> **Can anybody help and explain to me why?**
>   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a **new** `ThreadPoolExecutor` every time `isOk` is called, and you **never shut it down**.

You only ever submit one job to the executor, so even use an executor, and not just create a new thread?

Either use plain threads, or re-use an executor maintained outside the method.

Comment: Oh myyy!, thank you @Andreas, i miss the threadPoolExecutor.shutdown or purge methods. By the way, i will take your advice to reuse it. Thanks again